# JSF wrap some elements in a list with a div

Tags: html, jsf, jstl

I need to generate some html like this:

```
<div class='element'>element</div>
<div class='element'>element</div>
<div class='element'>element</div>
<div class='more-elements'>
    <div class='element'>element</div>
    <div class='element'>element</div>
    <div class='element'>element</div>
</div>
```

basically, the elements after the third must be inside another div tag. I tried this code:

```
<c:set var="hasMore" value="0"/>
<c:forEach items="${elements}" var="element" varStatus="loop">
    <c:if test="${loop.index eq 3}">
        <c:set var="hasMore" value="1"/>
        <div class='more-elements'>
    </c:if>
    <div class='element'>${element.name}</div>
</c:forEach>
<c:if test="{hasMore eq 1}">
    </div>
</c:if>
```

But then when it tries to render the page I've got an  `No end tag found.` exception.

What is the proper way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then try this code:

```
<c:set var="hasMore" value="0"/>
<c:forEach items="${elements}" var="element" varStatus="loop">
<c:if test="${loop.index lt 3}">
    <div class='element'>${element.name}</div>     
</c:if>

<c:if test="${loop.index ge 3}">
  <div class='element'>
    <c:set var="hasMore" value="1"/>
    <div class='more-elements'>${element.name}
    </div> 
  </div> 
</c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question because I already had the </div> tag inside the <c:if>

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `<c:out/>` tag:

```
<c:set var="hasMore" value="0"/>
<c:forEach items="${elements}" var="element" varStatus="loop">
    <c:if test="${loop.index eq 3}">
        <c:set var="hasMore" value="1"/>
        <c:out value="<div class='more-elements'>" escapeXml="false"/>
    </c:if>
    <div class='element'>${element.name}</div>
</c:forEach>
<c:if test="{hasMore eq 1}">
    <c:out value="</div>" escapeXml="false" />
</c:if>
```